# What year is my bmx diamondback

Tags: bmx

Serial number is F5065423 there's also another number is fw22107 I can't find it on the Internet. Need to know what year was it made.

Thanks

Comment: Can we ask why you need to know what year it was made?  What's your goal here?  Its not like a car where two adjacent years may have incompatible parts.

Comment: Serial numbers are useless for identifying year. Manufactures don't provide any info about their serial numbers.